# How do I use the ExitCode on the TFS InvokeProcess activity?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In TFS build I call to a nant script using a custom activity InvokeProcess (we use NANT till we will be able to move to "TFS language")
I want to fail the build if NANT fails. I guess I should use the Result property of the InvokeProcess.
How I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you can find what you need [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/11/09/Part-15-Fail-a-build-based-on-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application.aspx).